# Как подключиться к удаленной БД mysql?

Tags: mysql

Извиняюсь если вопрос или данные некорректны. В этом вопросе я полный нуб.

Имеется зарубежный хостинг 100webspace.com c поддержкой mysql. Все что я там нашел:

MySQL Server: localhost

MySQL Host: mysql.100ws.com

Phpmyadmin соединяется к бд по 10.123.0.85 : 3306.

Ip моего компа добавлен в панели управления сайта для подключения к удаленной бд.
Пробую в консоли win7 : telnet 10.123.0.85 3306 - Сбой подключения. Что делать?

Comment: что конкретно выдает telnet?

Comment: Не удалось открыть подключение к этому узлу на порт 3306 : Сбой подключения

Comment: а по 443 или 80 что выдает?

Comment: по 80 подключилось, по 443 нет

Comment: `10.123.0.85` ­— это адрес локальной подсети, если ты с сервером не соединён каким-нить VPN'ом, то само собой по нему не подключишься... ИМХО этот вопрос лучше задать в тех. поддержку...

Comment: ЕМНИП 100webspace.com не предоставляет к MySQL удалённого доступа. Только локальный.